# Conversion of EBCDIC code to ASCII

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to convert EBCDIC code to ASCII code.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216399

Comment: Thanks. Getting "conversion failed". I don't know what i am doing wrong. Actually i am sending data to IBM Server and Getting response from server. As IBM server support EBCDIC and i am stuck here.

Comment: @indu: As I understand it, there are several variants of EBCDIC, perhaps that is the problem. Can you somehow provide a hex dump of a EBCDIC string for which the conversion fails? Then one could try to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an encoding for [EBCDIC 037](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimals_Interchange_Code#EBCDIC_037)
in the iOS Foundation frameworks.
The following example shows how to use this:

```
// EBCDIC string  "hello!"
char ebcdicString[] = { 0x88, 0x85, 0x93, 0x93, 0x96, 0x5A, 0 };

// Convert EBCDIC to NSString:
NSStringEncoding cp037 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingEBCDIC_CP037);
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:ebcdicString length:strlen(ebcdicString) encoding:cp037];

// Convert NSString to ASCII:
char asciiBuf[20];
if ([string getCString:asciiBuf maxLength:sizeof(asciiBuf) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) {
    printf("%s\n", asciiBuf);
} else {
    printf("conversion failed\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 Truly speaking Today only I encountered `EBCDIC` .